When I run angular project, I get error ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-chart.js and primeng-editor.js
When I run angular project, I get error
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-chart.js and primeng-editor.js

I use

Angular version 8
Node 14.21.3
primeng 9

I try delete node_modules, package-lock.json and clear npm catch but it didn't work

My auto import use wrong import
I fix it by
change
import { FileUpload } from "primeng";

to
import { FileUpload } from "primeng/fileupload";

